# extends Model == extends Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

All the examples of Eloquent Models in Laravel 4 extends Eloquent, but when you generate a Model in Laravel 5 it says extends Model, are they the same?

Laravel 4

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    //Code

}
```

Laravel 5

```
<?php

class User extends Model {

    //Code

}
```

The Laravel 5 [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage) says:

> Defining An Eloquent Model
>
> ```
> class User extends Model {}
> ```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes they are the same. Laravel 4 uses Class Aliasing to map `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` to `Eloquent`. You can see in the `app/config/app.php` file:

```
'Eloquent'          => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
```

Laravel 5 uses namespacing instead. So at the top of the model class you will see this line:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Comment: I'm just getting started with Laravel, v5.6.  My model has BOTH `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;` AND `class XYZ extends Eloquent` -- is having BOTH okay?

> <?php
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
> class User extends Eloquent {`

Comment: @Genki, yes. The `use ... as ...` statement is a way of aliasing a class name but only in that file. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

used...

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

to extend the model

Answer (score 0):

I am using the _ide_helper.php file 
from barryvdh's laravel-ide-helper

The subclass there is also called Eloquent and extends to Model.

So if I extend my own model class to Eloquent, the IDE knows all the functions, like MyModelClass::find. Maybe there's another way to do it, but that really works for me.